# How can sharepoint answer to 80 and 443 with the same name

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-addin, ssl

I have a sharepoint site collection that answers to http://myserver. I have an urgent demand to go to SSL, so the same site should respond to https://myserver. The problem is that I have MANY javascript files that have as a source the http://myserver/javascript/, so I need the same site to answer both.

Is this feasible?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This is will depend on where you will install SSL certificate!

- On the SharePoint Server.or
- On the LoadBalancer.

**In case of** you `install SSL on the server` you will just need to adjust `Alternative Access Mapping` and all links will be served automatically as HTTPS

**In case of** you `enable SSL on the load balancer`, not on the server. so you will get

> This page is trying to load scripts from unauthenticated sources

This error usually occurs if the current page has been hosted within a secure HTTPS environment. Meanwhile, it embeds unsecured HTTP contents/scripts.

So, in this case, you will need to

- Enable **[Mixed content in your browser](https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/04/03/only-secure-content-is-displayed-allow-display-mixed-content/)** as a temporary solution
- or Configure **SSL offloading** on the load balancer. For more details check [THIS PAGE IS TRYING TO LOAD SCRIPTS FROM UNAUTHENTICATED SOURCES DURING STARTING AN APPROVAL WORKFLOW IN SHAREPOINT 2013](https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/04/20/this-page-is-trying-to-load-scripts-from-unauthenticated-sources-when-starting-approval-workflow-in-sharepoint-2013/)

Also, in specific cases when you tried to run API like `ProjectServer.SVC` or approve document...etc you will face the below error:

> This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

In this case, you will need to install the SSL certificate on the server to avoid this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you may learn the hard way that it's not the best to hard code the local server name into the script references. I'd go back and change references to relative paths. That way, the scripts will work, even if the site is migrated to a different farm (like what should be happening when backups are tested, for QA, etc.)